# TypeError: g_accReqCSRBridgeSPSecToGrps is undefined

Tags: 2013, error, access, request-management

we have a lot of site collection here. The things is depending of the site, when the manager wants to answer an Access Request, they get this error message.

Weird stuff, the message is not the same depending of the browser

Here is the message on Firefox:

[image]

And here is the message on the same site with IE:
[image]

Already checked the log and also the console in case of any JS failure but i've found nothing.

Thanks for your help